# Dragon Quest IX: Skill to prevent enemies from escaping?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

Is there a class skill in Dragon Quest IX to prevent enemies from escaping? If so which class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are certain skills that can stun the enemies for 1 turn, such as roar for the martial artist, but no skill that prevents escaping for all enemies.  Also, these skills typically do not work on the metal slimes, you just have to prepare for them carefully before attempting to level up using them.  I.e. have 4 sword users with metal slash ready in case they don't escape the first round.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such skill. It would make the game too easy to level up in. Since if such skill exist it would prevent those silver blobs from escaping.